# Version Difference in LINEST function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to debug an issue I'm having with the LINEST function. It appears that I'm getting different results depending on version. Particularly Excel 2007 vs. later versions.

For....reasons... I am attempting to produce a quadratic regression that uses only a subset of the values. The trick is that subset can change dynamically based on user input.

Here's the data for the particular case where I identified the bug:

```
 Y   keep     x     x^2 
 1     1   .0001   .00000001
 2     1   .0001   .00000001
 3     1   .0024   .00000576
 4     1   .0024   .00000576
 5     1   .0037   .00000729
 6     0       0           0
 7     0       0           0
 8     0       0           0
 9     0       0           0
10     0       0           0
```

I am using the keep variable to produce the intercept. Here's the actual function I'm using to get the coefficients:

```
b2: LINEST(Table[y], Table[[keep]:[x^2]], FALSE, FALSE)
b1: INDEX(LINEST(Table[y], Table[[keep]:[x^2]], FALSE, FALSE),2)
b0: INDEX(LINEST(Table[y], Table[[keep]:[x^2]], FALSE, FALSE),3)
```

This seems to work correctly in later versions of excel and I get a value of 1588628.76 for b2. In Excel 2007, I'm getting a value of 0. Clearly that is a problem.

I have not been able to find any documented differences in the implementation of LINEST between versions. Is anyone aware of what the difference is and how I might be able to make this function robust to version differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more thought, I decided it best to just revert to the math to ensure a robust solution. Here's what I used:

```
b2:  =INDEX(MMULT(MMULT(MINVERSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(Table[[keep]:[x^2]]),Table[[keep]:[x^2]])),TRANSPOSE(Table[[keep]:[x^2]])),Table[y]),3)
b1:  =INDEX(MMULT(MMULT(MINVERSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(Table[[keep]:[x^2]]),Table[[keep]:[x^2]])),TRANSPOSE(Table[[keep]:[x^2]])),Table[y]),2)
b0:  =INDEX(MMULT(MMULT(MINVERSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(Table[[keep]:[x^2]]),Table[[keep]:[x^2]])),TRANSPOSE(Table[[keep]:[x^2]])),Table[y]),1)
```